# How to handle solr disconnection in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, exception, solr, solarium

I implement search functionalities with the help of solr via solarium in CodeIgniter.

I'm starting my website without solr connection (i.e. If the solr connection is stopped), My website throws the below warning message,

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Solarium\Exception\HttpException
>
> Message: Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to localhost port 8983: Connection refused
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\project-folder\project-name\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl.php
>
> Line Number: 170

My doubt is if any chance to add exception handling in solr connection.

That means, If solr status is true it works as it is. If the solr status is false (Not in connection) the error warning is not displayed.

This above scenario is possible or not by using exception handling.

**Update**

My controller page,

```
        function __construct()
        {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->config->load('solarium');
          $this->client = new Solarium\Client($this->config->item('solarium_endpoint'));
        }

        public function solrQuery() 
        {
            $query = $this->client->createSelect();

            $query->setStart(0)->setRows(1000);

            // get the facetset component
            $facetSet = $query->getFacetSet();

            $facetSet->createFacetField('product_category_1')->setField('product_category_1');

            $categories_data = $this->client->select($query);
        }
```

Comment: where is this code initialized in codeigniter? surround that in a try catch block like with any other exception based system.

Comment: No. I use code directly in my code

Comment: And I add my code with my question

Comment: and why can't you surround it in a try catch block? nothing in your code suggests you can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the relevant bits of code that throw exceptions in a try-catch block like so:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->config->load('solarium');
    try {
        $this->client = new Solarium\Client($this->config->item('solarium_endpoint'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function solrQuery() {
    try {
        $query = $this->client->createSelect();

        $query->setStart(0)->setRows(1000);

        // get the facetset component
        $facetSet = $query->getFacetSet();

        $facetSet->createFacetField('product_category_1')->setField('product_category_1');

        $categories_data = $this->client->select($query);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Of course you don't have yo use `show_error()` and can instead return false, or set your own headers and your own message.